# Connect to SQL Server using SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, odbc, pyodbc, unixodbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server Express database using SQLALchemy and pyodbc, but I'm continuously getting the error:

> (pyodbc.Error) ('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data
>   source name not found, and no default driver specified (0)
>   (SQLDriverConnect)')

And I really don't understand if my engine url is wrong or what else.
My scenario is the following:

- I'm on a **Mac**
- I have a **docker** container (based on a **Debian** image with `unixodbc` and `unixodbc-dev`) in which my python app tries to connect to...
- a **virtualbox** virtual machine running **windows 8** with SQL express 2014...

I configured a user for the SQL express, with SQL Server authentication:

- user: ar_user
- password: ar_psw

...then:

- I configured TCP ports as 1433 and disabled dynamic ports (SQL Server Configuration Manager > Network Configurations > Protocols).
- I turned off Windows Firewall.
- I used an Host-only adapter for the VM running windows8

now...

The VM is accessible from the host (my mac), since a:

```
ping -c 3 vm-ip
```

succeed!

But although I tried every possible permutation of user, password, ip, server name and port:

- `'mssql+pyodbc://ar_user:ar_psw@vm-ip/master'`
- `'mssql+pyodbc://ar_user:ar_psw@vm-ip:1433/master'`
- `'mssql+pyodbc://IE10WIN8\\SQLEXPRESS'`
- `'mssql+pyodbc://ar_user:ar_psw@IE10WIN8\\SQLEXPRESS'`
- `'mssql+pyodbc://ar_user:ar_psw@IE10WIN8\\SQLEXPRESS:1433'`
- `'mssql+pyodbc://ar_user:ar_psw@IE10WIN8\\SQLEXPRESS:1433/master'`

...and many more!

I always get the "datasource not found error".
What should I do?

ps: the vm is pingable even in the docker container!

**UPDATE (solved but not 100%):**

I solved in this way:

I configured FreeTDS driver using `/etc/odbcinst.ini` in this way:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = TDS driver (Sybase/MS SQL)
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
client charset = UTF-8
```

and in `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`:

```
[global]
tds version = 7.3
client charset = UTF-8
```

Then I created the engine using the following string:

```
'mssql+pyodbc://my_user:my_psw@machine_ip:1433/my_db?driver=FreeTDS'
```

It seems to work properly, but I get this warning:

> SAWarning: Unrecognized server version info '95.12.255'.   Version
>   specific behaviors may not function properly.   If using ODBC with
>   FreeTDS, ensure TDS_VERSION 7.0 through 7.3, not 4.2, is configured in
>   the FreeTDS configuration.

I also defined the TDS version using environment variables but it doesn't fix the issue... any idea?

Comment: Check the documentation [here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html#connecting-to-pyodbc). You either need to supply a DSN name (as defined in your "odbc.ini" file) or you need to explicitly supply the `driver=` name in the connection URL. In your case a DSN connection would probably be the safest choice.

Comment: Gord is on right, DSN is the way to go. Also, make sure you've forwarded the appropriate ports (1433) from guest VM to host Mac.

Comment: check my updated notes ;)

Comment: @GordThompson and FlipperPA are correct. That seems like the ideal way to go about this. Alternatively, I recommend you use pymssql: https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql. Basic stress testing indicates it is slightly more performant than pyodbc

Comment: I tried to connect with both "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=" and params = parse.quote(
        "Driver={{FreeTDS}};Server={};Port=1433;"
        "Database={};UID={};PWD={};"
        .format(db_host, db_name, db_user, db_pass))
    create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(params) and both times I got base.py:1586: SAWarning: Unrecognized server version info '95.12.255'.   If using ODBC with FreeTDS, ensure TDS_VERSION 7.0 through 7.3, not 4.2, is configured in the FreeTDS configuration.
  ".".join(str(x) for x in self.server_version_info))

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a tutorial [here](http://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/databases/connecting-to-sql-server-with-sqlalchemy) of how to do this. Essentially, you need to:

1. `brew install unixodbc`
2. `brew install freetds --with-unixodbc`
3. Add the freetds driver to odbcinst.ini
4. Add a DSN (Domain Source Name) to odbc.ini named "MY_DSN"
5. `pip install pyodbc`
6. `e = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://username:password@MY_DSN")`

[The walkthrough here](http://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/databases/connecting-to-sql-server-with-sqlalchemy) does a much more thorough job of explaining this, including issues with SQL Server/FreeTDS Protocol Version Compatibility.